# Applescript: Am I able to save a text file using a variable for the filename and file path?

Tags: applescript, bbedit

I have created a script to find/replace within the document to create an SQL insert statement, but so far I have been unable to create a statement that allows me to save the results using a saved variable (the date) and extension (.sql) to a different folder.

```
tell (current date) to set {_year, _month, _day} to {year, it's month, day}
set _day to text -2 thru -1 of ("00" & _day) -- add leading zeros if needed
set _month to text -2 thru -1 of ("00" & (_month as integer)) -- add leading zeros if needed
set _year to text -4 thru -1 of ("00" & (_year as integer))
set _date to _year & _month & _day

save text document 1 to file "Filepath:" & fileName without saving as stationery
```

This results in the following error:

> error "BBEdit got an error: Can’t get file \"Filepath:\"." number -1728 from file "Macintosh HD:Users:Filepath:"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This saves `BBEdit`'s `text document 1` as `fileName` (with extension `.sql`)
 to the `desktop folder`:

Version that uses the `do shell script` command to create the datestamp:

```
set fileName to (do shell script "/bin/date +%Y-%m-%d") & ".sql"
set filePath to ((path to desktop folder) as text) & fileName

tell application "BBEdit"
    if exists text document 1 then
        save text document 1 to file filePath
    else
        beep
    end if
end tell
```

Version that uses AppleScript's `date` to create the datestamp:

```
set fileName to my stringForDate("") & ".sql"
set filePath to ((path to desktop folder) as text) & fileName

tell application "BBEdit"
    if exists text document 1 then
        save text document 1 to file filePath
    else
        beep
    end if
end tell

on stringForDate(aDate)
    if aDate is "" then set aDate to (the current date)
    try
        set dYear to year of (aDate) as number
        set dMonth to month of (aDate) as number
        set dDay to day of (aDate) as number
        if dMonth < 10 then set dMonth to "0" & dMonth
        if dDay < 10 then set dDay to "0" & dDay
        return ((dYear & "-" & dMonth & "-" & dDay) as string)
    on error
        return "-ERROR"
    end try
end stringForDate
```

If one wants to check if the file is already there, insert this after the `filePath` is set up:

```
tell application "Finder"
    if exists file filePath then
        beep
        display dialog "Overwrite existing file?" buttons {"Overwrite", "Cancel"} default button 2
        if the button returned of the result is "Cancel" then
            return
        end if
    end if
end tell
```

---

**Addition**
Here a little help to put the path you want into the clipboard. Execute following code in a script and select the folder you want to store the files in:

```
set rootFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Pick a folder…") as string
set the clipboard to rootFolder
```

Now that path is in the clipboard and ready to get pasted in.
 Example: `DiskName:Users:shortusername:Desktop:rootFolder:`

Now replace

```
set filePath to ((path to desktop folder) as text) & fileName
```

with

```
set filePath to "DiskName:Users:shortusername:Desktop:rootFolder:" & fileName
```

*Of course, "DiskName:Users:shortusername:Desktop:rootFolder:" is an example for the text in your clipboard.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I don't want to save on the Desktop, I need to save in a folder, as it's for a daily email I get and I want all the daily files stored in the correct folder. In your example "set filePath to ((path to desktop folder) as text) & fileName" how can I set that filepath to the folder I need? Thanks!

Comment: See ADDITION. Hope it helps.

Comment: @ Zero, I optimized your stringForDate handler slightly, since I liked it, I felt it better to post it below, than in the comments, since it looses the carriage returns/newlines here.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly optimized version of Zero's stringForDate handler

```
 on stringForDate(aDate)
     if aDate is "" then set aDate to (the current date)
     if class of aDate is not date then return null
     set {year:dYear, month:dMonth, day:dDay} to aDate
     set dMonth to dMonth as integer
     if dMonth < 10 then set dMonth to "0" & dMonth
     if dDay < 10 then set dDay to "0" & dDay
     return ((dYear & "-" & dMonth & "-" & dDay) as string)
 end stringForDate
```